# How to use a variable from arbitrary type class?

Tags: c#, arrays, class

I have a method, which takes an array of arbitrary type. And I have an array of objects (in my case this is a class with variable). Then I put my array of objects in this method. So how can I use a variable from this object?

```
public class C           // This one of my classes
{
    public int I { get; set; }
}

public static void Sort<T>(T[] array, string name) // Here i put my class as argument
{
    ...
    Array.Sort<T>(array, (a, b) => a.I.CompareTo(b.I)); // Here "I" is some variable in my class, which i need to use
    ...
}

static void Main(string[] args) // Here i create an array of classes
{
    ...
    C[] classes = new C[100000];
    Sort(classes);
    ...
}
```

Comment: How would you expect this to work if you pass in a `string[]` or any other kind of array? If you only need the `Sort` method to work with `C[]`, just don't make it generic...

Comment: Is `classes[]` homogeneous (i.e., are all the types in the array of the same type)? If no, what does `Sort` mean (consider an array of people, cars, trees and houses, how would you sort them together)

Comment: @Flydog57
Yes, classes is homogeneous. They contains only 1 int variable with random number

Comment: You can always cast your object to dynamic and call `((dynamic)obj).I`

Comment: Can they all implement an interface that exposes that int? Then you can have an array of `IHaveAnInt` instances

Comment: Yes, an Interface as the way to go here.

Comment: Or implement IComparable on the class(es) and have a type constraint like where T:IComparable and then you can do a.CompareTo(b) and the "I" member becomes an implementation detail of IComparable. Actually if the class implements IComparable you can probably just do .Sort() and call it a day

Comment: @Flydog57
Thank you for your answer, but i can't understand it correctly. May you present some sample of code, please?

Comment: Aren't you missing the `where T : C` constraint in `Sort<T>()`?

Comment: The `Array.Sort` method can take an `IComparer<T>` as an argument. Instead of making your types implement `IComparable`, create a second type that knows how to compare your types. Create the `IHaveAnInt` interface (that I made up above) that has an int property getter. Make all your types implement that interface. The create a type that implements `IComparer<IHaveAnInt>` that understands how to compare two IHaveAnInts. Pass an instance of that type to `Array.Sort`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you implement the [IComparable<T>](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.icomparable-1) interface in your class, and you will not even need a dedicated sorting method

Please consider the following sample code

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Test
{
    class Comparable : IComparable<Comparable>
    {
        public int Number { get; set; }

        public int CompareTo(Comparable other)
        {
            if (other == null)
                return 1;

            return Number.CompareTo(other.Number);
        }

    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            List<Comparable> comparableList = new List<Comparable>
            {
                new Comparable { Number = 75 },
                new Comparable { Number = 1 },
                new Comparable { Number = 23 }
            };

            comparableList.Sort();

            foreach (Comparable comparable in comparableList)
                Console.WriteLine(comparable.Number);
        }

    }
}
```

**EDIT**

If you, as indicated in your comment, must use the `Array.Sort()` method, then you can easily convert the list to an array and do so

```cs
Comparable[] comparableArray = comparableList.ToArray();
Array.Sort(comparableArray);
foreach (Comparable comparable in comparableArray)
    Console.WriteLine(comparable.Number);
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, but i must use Array.Sort() method, according to my task

Comment: You can easily convert the list to an array and do so: please see the edit to my answer

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```
public class C  
{
    public int I { get; set; }
}

public class CComparer : IComparer<C>
{
    public int Compare(C x, C y)
    {
        return x.I.CompareTo(y.I);
    }
}

static class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var array = new C[100];

        // Calls CComparer.Compare(x,y);
        Array.Sort(array, new CComparer());
    }
}
```

---

An alternate version is

```
public class C  
{
    public int I { get; set; }

    public static IComparer<C> Comparer { get; } = new CComparer();

    class CComparer : IComparer<C>
    {
        internal CComparer() { }
        public int Compare(C x, C y)
        {
            return x.I.CompareTo(y.I);
        }
    }
}

static class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var array = new C[100];

        Array.Sort(array, C.Comparer);
    }
}
```